# Java: deriving a classpath from javap?

Tags: java, maven

How can I derive a classpath from running javap?

Here's a maven-generated project, in which I seem to be able to run the hello-world application, but not the test program.

This works:

```
~/junk11/hello $ javap target/classes/net/markharrison/App.class 
Compiled from "App.java"
public class net.markharrison.App {
  public net.markharrison.App();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

~/junk11/hello $ java -cp target/classes net.markharrison.App
Hello World!
```

But not the AppTest class:

```
~/junk11/hello $ javap target/test-classes/net/markharrison/AppTest.class 
Compiled from "AppTest.java"
public class net.markharrison.AppTest extends junit.framework.TestCase {
  public net.markharrison.AppTest(java.lang.String);
  public static junit.framework.Test suite();
  public void testApp();
}
~/junk11/hello $ java -cp target/test-classes net.markharrison.AppTest
Error: Could not find or load main class net.markharrison.AppTest
```

The test runs from Maven:

```
~/junk11/hello $ mvn test -q
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running net.markharrison.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
```

What piece of the puzzle am I missing?

Comment: there is no `main` method anyway ?? ,, May be maven is helping to test create its own method and testing your class.

Comment: AppTest is not a main class. It's a test, that is supposed to be executed by JUnit. You thus obviously need JUnit in the classpath, and the main class should be the JUnit runner. Fortunately, you don't need to figure that out by yourself, since the tests are meant to be run using Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the test case uses junit, AppTest has no main method to call.  This can be determined by the command line as follows:

```
$ javap AppTest.class |fgrep 'public static void main(java.lang.String[])'
$ if test $?; then echo can be run; fi
```